# UI Grid Expandable option not showing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui-grid

I have been following this [tutorial](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#!/tutorial/Tutorial:%20216%20Expandable%20grid) and struggling to get expandable rows to show in the UI.

My attempt so far has been. Data is populated by a click event.

AngularJS

```
angular.module("directives").controller("Controller", ["service", "$scope",
      function (service, $scope) {

      var GetRowTemplate = function()
      {
        var rowTemplate = '<div ui-grid="row.entity.subGridOptions" style="height:150px;"></div>'
        return rowTemplate;
      }

      $scope.gridOptions = {                  
        enableRowSelection: true,
        expandableRowTemplate: GetRowTemplate(),
        expandableRowHeight: 150,
        expandableRowScope: {
            subGridVariable: 'subGridScopeVariable'
          }
       }   
      
      $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [            
        { field: 'id'},
        { field: 'name'},
        { field: 'age'},
        { field: 'address.city'}
      ];

        $scope.filterData = function (valid) {
        if (valid)
        {
            var startDate = $scope.dateRange.startDate;
            var endDate = $scope.dateRange.endDateDate;
            
            var userId = $scope.selectedUser != undefined ? $scope.selectedUser.priceNetUserId : null;            
            var subWidgetId = $scope.selectedSubWidget != null ? $scope.selectedSubWidget.WidgetSubItems.subItemId.subItemId : 0;
            var widgetId = $scope.selectedWidget != undefined ? $scope.selectedWidget.id : 0;

            auditService.getFilterData(startDate, endDate, userId, widgetId, subWidgetId,
                function(data) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                    {                                                                
                        data[i].subGridOptions = {
                            columnDefs: [{name: 'Id', field: 'id'}, {name: 'Name', 
                                          field: 'name'}],
                            data: data[i].friends,
                        };
                    }
                    $scope.gridOptions.data = data;
                });
              
               vm.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function(gridApi){
                   vm.gridApi = gridApi;
               };

      }
}
```

HTML

```
<div ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-pinning ui-grid-expandable class="grid"></div>
```

This is how the UI looks without the expandable rows

Gone through the tutorial few times and not able to figure out why it won't show the expandable rows?

[image]

Should look like this....

[image]